# Auto center UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, position

I'm a bit stuck with horizontal position on views.
I have a lot a views in a view container (that's bigger than subviews total width).

All views must be horizontally centered.
If a subview is marked as hidden (or with a zero alpha), the position of the others must change to be centered again.

Do you have an idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from rearranging the views when you show/hide one of the subviews?

Comment: No but how can I rearrange them ?

Comment: by setting their frame or center property.

Comment: I must be tired ;) I know I have to change frame or center but I'm stucked about have to determine coordinates (x only)

Comment: There's no way to change just the X coordinate. You have to reset the frame (CGRect - all 4 values) or the center point (CGPoint - 2 values).  There are lots of categories floating around out there that can simplify this.  I use one that gives me a setCenterX: method, so you can do someView.centerX = whatever;

Comment: I know how to manipulate frame and centers and how to simplify setters . I was "just" blocked on calculation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.  I pass the container into the function, determine the width of all the visible subviews, and get the x offset from the container width and the width of the visible subviews.  From there, you can update the frame of the visible subviews and they should be centered horizontally.

```
-(void)centerViews:(UIView*)container {
   CGFloat width = 0.0;
   for(UIView *view in container.subviews) {
       if(view.alpha > 0.0) {
           width += view.frame.size.width;
       }
   }

   CGFloat xOffset = (container.frame.size.width - width) / 2.0;

   for(UIView *view in container.subviews) {
       if(view.alpha > 0.0) {
           [view setFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

            xOffset += view.frame.size.width;
       }
   }      
}
```

You'll have to update this to include any padding you have between views.

Comment: Ok I wrote this but forgot mess up with xOffset. Thanks you !